# How to redirect a url to call a specific xsjs file?

Tags: sapui5, hana

If I have a url called `https://hostname:port/service/session`.
How do I make it redirect to call my xsjs file called `session.xsjs` which returns session info in json format.

I was reading regarding SAP Hana XS configuration on below link:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.00/en-US/86c9d3762a6b47039346f8ef075f8a7a.html#loio86c9d3762a6b47039346f8ef075f8a7a__section_xxg_dlr_v4

But unable to find anything concrete. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

We can redirect the url to a specific xsjs file in the .xsaccess rewrite_rules property.

Link for the documentation:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/52715f71adba4aaeb480d946c742d1f6/2.0.02/en-US/8067eabb21af4448b73895982ec394a4.html

Solution for my example:

```
`"rewrite_rules" : [{
            "source": "/service/session",
            "target": "session.xsjs"
     }],`
```